# How do I search Mail.app by country code?

Tags: macos, mail.app, search

I want to look at just the emails sent to me from the `.ru` (or any other domain code), and I'm not having ay luck. Searching `from:.ru` or`from:".ru"` doesn't work. A wildcard approach doesn't work either. Anybody out there know the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a smart mailbox where "From" "ends with" "ru".

Answer (score 1):

Just type `.ru` in the search box, hit enter, then click the **Any** drop down that appears and change it to **From**.

Comment: But that also captures, to make up an example, `dan.rush@email.com`.